# Best practices for managing different libraries for variations of a sensor

Tags: c++, embedded-systems

Due to the previous supply chain issues, I currently have multiple variations of a particular sensor that performs a function in my design. Each of these variations have their own library associated with them, however, they all use the same functions names so that it's easy for me to swap between variations when sensor is out of stock. Our code is written in C++, and I wanted to know if there are any practices I should use to maintain these libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there is some danger of using sensorA with libraryB.

Hopefully there is a way we can interrogate the attached
sensor and find that it is A, B, or C.
Failing that, it goes into a config file and we take
care to get it right each time.

Similarly, we should be able to call a function and learn
which library is loaded.
Then it is simple to throw fatal error if sensor & library are mismatched.

Using environment variables to alter the behavior
of the `ldd` dynamic linker might be a convenient
way to select proper library.
A shell script could interrogate the attached sensor
and then choose the right library.
If a thing can be automated it should be automated,
to eliminate needless sources of error.

---

In addition to unit tests you will need to write
down a System test, a script for humans to follow.
It needs to alter the physical environment,
and verify correct sensor output being reported.

You need to run at least three such tests,
to validate each sensor variant.
Consider running another six tests that have
deliberately mismatched library version,
so you can better understand failure cases.
For example, you might notice an opportunity
to add a sanity check that reports "bad config file!"
in case of human error where the file doesn't
match actual config.
Exhaustively studying mismatches,
and recording the results,
may also reduce your cost of handling
certain problem reports from the field.

Be sure to label sensor variants in a way that
lets field staff identify them even with the
power turned off, and without *too* much
disassembly required.